# Can't understand the behavior of async,await in c#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am learning the await async feature of c#. But the behavior of the bellow code is confusing me.

```
public static async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync() {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient() {
        MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000
    };
    Task <int> download1 = ProcessUrlAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com", client);
    Task <int> download2 = ProcessUrlAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/67w7t67f.aspx", client);
    int length1 = await download1;
    int length2 = await download2;
    Console.WriteLine("Sum is {0}", length1 + length2);
}

public static async Task <int> ProcessUrlAsync(string url, HttpClient client) {
    Console.WriteLine("I am here to process {0}", url);
    var byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine("processing is completed {0}", url);

    return byteArray.Length;
}
```

What I am expecting is after completing download1 and download2 the last line of the CreateMultipleAsync() will execute and sum of lengths will be printed.
The problem is the last line is never executing!

Comment: How are you calling that method? Do you see any of the other messages?

Comment: I am only seeing the  first message in the ProcessUrlAsync method.
I am calling the  CreateMultipleTasksAsync() method from another method which just await it, named StartMultiple() and called that method from constructor.

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve]. (FWIW, when I run this code I get a failure in the second URL:  System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel)

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rBccHq4HXD/   here is my enire code

Comment: Um that's really not how to use a constructor. That is the whole problem. You need an async entry point, and a constructor must be synchronous. And honestly you shouldn't be performing heavy lifting in the constructor like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you execute `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()` method.
If you excute it from a sync method like this way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
    }
```

then you couldn't see the result of that last line. 
Why? Because this call is not awaited, so the `Main` method will continue, and ends, before  the call `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()` is completed. So you can't see the result of last line.
Let excute by this way, and you will get it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
        task.Wait();
    }
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yes that work for me! But also when I changed the code to this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VRHkMF5j5w/  and that also worked! can you please help me to understand the difference between await and directly getting GetAwaiter().GetResult() ?

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting.  Inside method `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()`, `await` will suspend its process and yield control to the method that call `CreateMultipleTasksAsync()`. While `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will wait for `ProcessUrlAsync()` completion. If you use async without await, your method is not really an async method.  Read this diagram and steps bellow it for more understand about await [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use async method in your constructor. Remove it from here.

Also, don't use `async void`. Instead you should use `async Task`:

```
class MultipleAsync
{
    public async Task StartMultiple()
    {
        await CreateMultipleTasksAsync();

    }
    public static async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };
        Task<int> download1 = ProcessUrlAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com", client);
        Task<int> download2 = ProcessUrlAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/67w7t67f.aspx", client);
        int length1 = await download1;
        int length2 = await download2;
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is {0}", length1 + length2);
    }
    public static async Task<int> ProcessUrlAsync(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am here to process {0}", url);
        var byteArray = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        Console.WriteLine("processing is completed {0}", url);

        return byteArray.Length;

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MultipleAsync multipleAsync = new MultipleAsync();
await multipleAsync.StartMultiple();
```

Also as your second task does not depend on the result of the first task, you can run two tasks in parallel. The second task will not wait for the completion of the first task:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };
Task<int> download1 = ProcessUrlAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com", client);
Task<int> download2 = ProcessUrlAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/67w7t67f.aspx", client);
var lengthts = await Task.WhenAll(download1, download2);
Console.WriteLine("Sum is {0}", lengthts.Sum());
```